# Can $\Phi$ measure of Integrated Information Theory serve as reward for reinforcement learning system?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, rewards, artificial-consciousness, integrated-information-theory

Can $\Phi$ measure (computed rigorously or approximately) of [Integrated Information Theory](https://journals.plos.org/ploscompbiol/article?id=10.1371/journal.pcbi.1004654) serve as reward for self-evolving/learning reinforcement learning system and hence we let this system to become/evolve into conscious system?

Comment: This is an old question, but can you please edit your post to explain what you mean by "$\Phi$ measure of IIT". Provide more details about this "$\Phi$ measure" and why you think it could server as the "reward signal" of an RL agent, as you seem to be suggesting.